# BIRT RCP report designer 4.6.0 problems: could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have installed BIRT RCP designer 4.6.0 on a server machine 64 with:
w12r2, java 1.7, eclipse Kepler 1.

when i start birt.exe i obtained a crash with this log:

```
!SESSION 2017-06-22 11:39:45.295 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples 4 0 2017-06-22 11:39:46.576
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples [51]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="3.10.0.v20160530-2011"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor [269]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20160505-1301"
              org.eclipse.jface.text [255]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-
```

......

and so on for all modules. Is it a problem due java 1.7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
```

is saying that Java 8 is required for the plugin.

There might also be other plugin version dependencies errors but you haven't included enough of the log to know for sure.

Note that the [Birt download page](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/) says that Eclipse Neon (4.6) is required.

Comment: In effect i've installed Birt 4.6.0 on my pc (w7 64 bit jre 1.8) and it's ok. I don't know why eclipse.org tells that birt rcp designer ìs compatible java 1.7.